# Is the continuous part of the symmetry group of a compact subset $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $SO(k)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-groups, topological-groups, isometry

Let $K$ be a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $G= \{f \in \mathrm{Isom}~\mathbb{R}^3 | f(K) = K\}$, $G'$ be the identity connected component of $G$. Is it true that $G'$ is isomorphic (as Lie group) $SO(k)$ for some $k \in \{1, 2, 3\}$?

P.S. Related my question [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316536/is-the-symmetry-group-of-a-compact-subset-of-mathbbrn-closed), there I asked about compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for arbitrary n the answer is no, see also comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413320/is-the-continuous-part-of-the-symmetry-group-of-a-compact-subset-mathbbrn)

Comment: If your $K$ is general, it might have $G = \{ id \}$.

Comment: What is $k{}{}$?

Comment: @ArcticChar In this case, G is isomorphic to SO (1).

Comment: @markvs I mean "there is k", of course (it is clear that in this case, for three-dimensional groups - SO (3), one-dimensional - SO (2), zero-dimensional - SO (1))

Comment: A closed connected subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is either trivial, the whole group, or conjugate to the standard upper left copy of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: @YCor I understand that this is exactly what needs to be proved (but the comment that the statement is true is certainly useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are already two answers to this question on MSE: [All connected closed subgroups in $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931074/all-connected-closed-subgroups-in-rmso3) and [Connected lie subgroup of $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114618/connected-lie-subgroup-of-so3)